# Create Check Constraint for Sum of rows with col value <= x

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

I'm building a database for an MMO for a class. I am trying to set a check constraint so a player can only equip so many items at once.

Here are some tables:

```
CREATE TABLE equipped_gear(
equipped_gear_id int not null IDENTITY
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.equipped_gear
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_equipped_gear PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (equipped_gear_id);

CREATE TABLE equipped_gear_contents(
content_id int not null IDENTITY,
equipped_gear_id int not null,
loot_id int not null
);

ALTER TABLE dbo.equipped_gear_contents
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_equipped_gear_contents PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (content_id);
```

So, each character has a unique `equipped_gear_id`. This will reference the `dbo.equipped_gear_contents` table where it will hold the value of the piece of loot they have equipped.

I want to create a check constraint for `dbo.equipped_gear_contents` so players can equip up to ten items. I've learned so far that I should create a trigger or a function. Other answers are close to what I want to accomplish, but nothing really hits the nail on the head.

Does anyone see a way to accomplish this?

Comment: for each equipped_gear_id in your dbo.equipped_gear_contents you want to have less than 11 rows? correct?

Comment: Maybe years of MMO's have tainted my creativity for what's possible, but wouldn't the equipped gear be tied to something like equipment slots (arms, legs, chest, blowhole) and that be the limiting factor? Yeah maybe there are 10 equipment slots, but they can't equip 10 helmets, right?